# Responsive navigation tabs i.e collapsible navigation tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to make navigation tab responsive just like navigation bar collapses on browser being resized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on following example:

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/

Try re-sizing the browser. Menu get converted to collapsed navigation.